# .htaccess to .hiawatha regex conversion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hiawatha

So i do not understand how the conversion from htaccess to hiawatha works. Can you suggest agood site or a good book to get into the topic?

My problem is the following conversion:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

htaccess

```
RequestURI exists Return
Match ^((?s).*)$ Rewrite /index.php?_url=/$1
```

hiawatha

But the Match Rewrite statement is wrong...

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: Hiawatha was not starting ...  because of the Match statement in the config.

Comment: just in case somebody is interested this is needed for tutorial 7: phalcon REST API [link](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for hiawatha URL TOOLKIT is:

```
RequestURI exists Return
Match ^/(.*) Rewrite /index.php?_url=/$1
```

This redirects everything to the index.php. 
For example
`http://host/get/123` rewrites to 
`http://host/index.php?_url=/get/123`